# How to delete from SQLite by last date?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Have a good day!
I have some trouble with SQLite, example:

I have a table where 2 columns:

```
Id    Date
11    2020-04-25 19:46:16Z
11    2020-04-25 19:46:19Z
*11   2020-04-25 19:46:25Z
12    2020-04-25 19:46:16Z
12    2020-04-25 19:46:19Z
```

I want to delete all rows (for example) where id = 11 and **not row with last date for id** 11 (in table *11 — I want to save)
I tried next commands:

```
DELETE FROM Messages WHERE UserId IS 11 AND Date IS (Select Date from Messages WHERE UserId IS 875658012 ORDER BY Date DESK LIMIT 184467440737095516 OFFSET 1) 
// Error: near DESK syntax error (Order by without DESK works but i can't OFFSET last)

DELETE FROM Messages WHERE UserId IS 11 AND Date IS MAX(Date)
// Error: misuse of aggregate function MAX()

DELETE FROM Messages WHERE (Select UserId=11 FROM Messages ORDER BY Date desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0)
// It deletes all :(
```

How can i fix it? ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 DELETE FROM Messages WHERE UserId = 11 AND Date < (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Messages WHERE UserId = 11 )
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to delete all rows (for example) where id = 11 and not row with last date for id 11 (in table *11 — I want to save) I tried next commands:

How about a correlated subquery?

```
delete from messages as m
    where m.id = 11 and
          m.date < (select max(m2.date) from messages m2 where m2.id = m.id);
```

Comment: And it was the first answer too.